A tag on my Asea motor says 415V-Y 240V-
What does the triangle represent?


Note that in both cases, the line voltage is 240V. In the Y connection, the voltage is line to line (line x 1.732 where 1.732 is tan60).

It means it's a 240V motor in delta connection.

An important thing to recognize is that your motor can be wired two different ways: -

Delta (a triangle symbol like this \$\Delta\$) or
Star (usually shown as a (\$\text{Y}\$ symbol)

If you connect the motor windings in star (\$\text{Y}\$) formation to a 3-phase 415 volt supply, each winding will receive 240 volts (because the relationship between line voltage and phase voltage is \$\sqrt3 : 1\$.
So, if you want to run your motor in delta formation you have the full line voltage across the windings and you must keep the supply voltage to \$\frac{415}{\sqrt3} = \text{239.600 volts}\$.

Typically we use a delta connection when a motor inverter is powered from a single phase.

@G36 Wouldn't that depend on the voltage? If in delta, and 240V a normal drive would not be able to give it full speed at nominal power?
